# Where to buy specialty Pokéballs?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I know that some of them can be bought in some Pokécenters, but can light balls and heavy balls be bought somewhere?

(I'd really like an exhaustive list, if possible).

Answer (score 5):

Poké Balls that can be purchased from shops:

**Anywhere**

- Poké Ball
- Great Ball
- Ultra Ball
- Premier Ball (by purchasing 10 Poké Balls)

**Route 2**

- Heal Ball
- Luxury Ball
- Nest Ball

**Royal Avenue**

- Heal Ball
- Nest Ball
- Timer Ball

**Paniola Town**

- Net Ball
- Repeat Ball
- Timer Ball

**Route 8**

- Dive Ball
- Dusk Ball
- Quick Ball

Any other Poké Ball, including the Apricot Balls from generation 2 games, can't be purchased, but Master Balls can be won from the Lottery in Hau'Oli Town, or the Big Dreams lottery in Festival Plaza.

Comment: Don't forget the general stores and ball stores from [Festival Plaza](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/festivalplaza.shtml).

Comment: @Isuka I don't see the point. I always have much, much more money than Festival Coins.

Comment: We were talking about an exhaustive list. Just wanted to help on making it complete. :p

Comment: I'd add it too. It's not really hard to get Festival coins (and I had no idea that was a thing)